# How can i move an appended div?

Tags: jquery-ui-draggable

I have this code:

```
<div id="plan">
    <div id="" class="move circle pe">1</div>
</div>

$('.move').draggable({
      containment: '#plan',
      stop: function(e, ui) {
        var offset = $(this).offset(),
          x = offset.left,
          y = offset.top;
        //callback will be here
        alert("posição x: " + x + " posição y:" + y);
      }
    });
```

I can move the div with Number 1 around, but when i generate a new div

```
function createStation(station){
        number = window.prompt("Escolha o numero para o posto");
        id = station+number;
        $("#plan").append("<div id='"+id+"' class='move circle pe'>"+number+"</div>");
    }
```

the div appears but i'm unable to move it.
i need to make it move but also alert its position (future callback)

Please check jsfiddle:

> https://jsfiddle.net/mornaistar/q180z7Ls/11/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make a extra function for binding `draggable()`, on every new item you 
 rebind class `move` to `draggable()` for example;

added a function `dragger()`

```
function dragger() {
    $('.move').draggable({
        containment: '#plan',
        stop: function(e, ui) {
            var offset = $(this).offset(),
                x = offset.left,
                y = offset.top;
            //callback para salvar em php
            alert("posição x: " + x + " posição y:" + y);
        }
    });
}
```

Fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/2f4c36v7/